# Assigning a string variable with the content in editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` where the user enters a name and I want this name to be assigned to a string variable for later use.

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final String value=et.getText().toString();
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tv.setText(value);
            }

        });
```

This is the code I am using. I enter some text in editText and when I click the button, the textView should display content in edittext. But when I click the button the textview becomes invisible i.e. it's having `null` value.

Comment: `final String value=et.getText().toString()` move into onclick.

Comment: worked for me.. i need reputations to mark this so sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your String value initialization inside the onClick, currently you have it initialized on as soon you get editText reference ... so it does not update to the text you have entered during runtime

New Code

```
final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String value=et.getText().toString();
                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tv.setText(value);
            }

        });
```

Comment: this is working. but if i want the text in edittext to be displayed in a different activity how does this work? my app is like, i enter name and age and submit it. when submitted it will redirect the page to another page where i need to display the contents of edittext

Comment: save it in sharedPreferences so that it persists during app session or directly pass to other activity as intent extra.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
    }

});
```

Comment: this is working. but if i want the text in edittext to be displayed in a different activity how does this work? my app is like, i enter name and age and submit it. when submitted it will redirect the page to another page where i need to display the contents of edittext

Comment: You can pass the value of the edittext as a parameter for the new activity

Comment: Have a look on this thread, maybe it will help you for pass parameter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: i tried the solution posted by user914425 and edited by Darshan Computing. it dint work. in the next activity the textboxes again go invisible

Comment: sorry. my bad. i put the parameter in wrong format. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String value;

OnCreate(){

EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                value=et.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(value);
            }

        });


}
```